# what's the difference between [*] and [**] in EditorConfig file

Tags: editorconfig

the [doc](http://editorconfig.org/#file-format-details) states:

> [*]    Matches any string of characters, except path separators (/)
>
> [**]   Matches any string of characters

However,the cases below take effect in both current root path and subdirectory. So what's the difference between [*] and [**] in EditorConfig file?

```
[*]
indent_style = space
indent_size = 2
```

and

```
[**]
indent_style = space
indent_size = 2
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`*` Matches any string of characters, except path separators `(/)`

`**` Matches any string of characters

Be sure to read the [documentation](http://editorconfig.org/)

Comment: can you give give an example that [\*\*] can matches while [\*] can't? Or explain why the [\*] and [\*\*] take effect in both current root path and subdirectory.

Comment: Check out the [example file](http://editorconfig.org/#example-file) and you will see `[lib/**.js]` which matches any `.js` file inside the `lib` directory. If you instead did `[lib/*.js]` it would only match `.js` files at the root of the `lib` directory, and not any files that are in subdirectories